# File Upload works fine in Visual Studio But fails in IIS

Tags: asp.net, api, exception, iis, fingerprint

File Upload works fine in Visual Studio Development Server. But when used Localhost/IIS Express, we are getting Stackoverflow Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is file creation permission issues is there. Please check the folder permission in which you trying to upload file.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for this reply. I am uploading the array of string to the finger print device. The array of string is the face template. We are using One API method for uploading face template. It works well on VSDServer. But when switched to IIS/IISEXpress we are getting stackoverflow exception.

Comment: I cannot even upload when debugging VS in localhost/IIS Express. It shows stackoverflow exception.

Comment: The face copy works when developed in a Desktop App.

Comment: Definitely some permission Issue.